# Amazon S3 enforcing access control

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have several PDF files stored in Amazon S3. Each file is associated with a user and only the file owner can access the file. I have enforced this in my download page. But the actual PDF link points to Amazon S3 url, which is accessible to anybody.

How do I enforce the access-control rules for this url?(without making my server a proxy for all the PDF download links)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using Amazon S3's [authenticated REST URLs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html) with an expiration date. They allow temporary, expiring access to a non-public S3 object.

That said, if they're going to share the URL, what's stopping them from sharing the file itself?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am aware of the second issue, but my client is worried about somebody guessing the URL(don't ask me how..).

Comment: On the bright side, they've latched onto the side of things you can actually control a bit. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Each file on your S3 account can have special access rights (ACL). You should set all your PDFs ACL to `private`. Then nobody will be able to access them.

S3 has an API which allows you to "temporarily" grant read-access. For example [Amazon's S3 PHP Library](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation) has a `getAuthenticatedURL (string $bucket, string $uri, integer $lifetime, [boolean $hostBucket = false], [boolean $https = false])` function.

This will enable you to allow access to a PDF for a defined amount of time (like 5 minutes) - which is more than enough if you immediatly redirect the user to S3.